# I have written code in GoLang then how to get chain code using Hyper-ledger Fabric Composer?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have set up **composer-rest-server** successfully using [this link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org)  on IBM cloud. I have written custom logic code in **GoLang** for getting chain code. I don't know how will proceed for next setup for getting chain code. Could you help me by showing me which way I have to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have linked to an external resource which is crucial for understanding your question. It is necessary to include the essential parts of your resource in your question, and ideally to provide the link for reference. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Chaincode for Hyperledger Composer is written in Javascript not GoLang. (Though Hyperledger Fabric supports both GoLang and Javascript with V1.1).

If you wish to proceed with Composer and Javascript, you could start with the [Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial), then follow this document for information on [Developing Applications](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/applications/applications-index).

**Update following Comment**

There is a [Fabric Tutorial "First Application"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) that uses go for the chaincode.

With regard to IBM cloud, it is possible to use Composer Business Networks, or write direct chaincode for the Fabric with IBM Cloud Starter Plan, and there are examples to "auto" deploy.

Comment: Thank you for response..Could u tell me  instead of Javascript  is their any GoLang link...And is there any document or link for getting chain code from composer and GoLang on IBM cloud?